# Drawing a circle on a map won't show up

Tags: swift, mapkit

I cannot figure out how to render the circle I am creating using a user's input from a prompt asking for the radius. I inherit the userMapView from another class but don't do anything with overlay rendering in that class so I never used the rendererForOverlay function until now. Do I need to add that function in the parent class or am I doing something else incorrectly?

```
@IBAction func addGeoFencePushed(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "How large would you like the geofence to be?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (_) in
        if let field = alertController.textFields?[0] {
            // store your data
            ALGlobal.sharedInstance.globalDefaults.set(field.text! as String, forKey: "geoFenceSize")
            let rad = field.text!
            self.drawGeoFence(radius: rad)
        } else {
            // user did not fill field
        }
    }
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func drawGeoFence(radius: String){
    let bagList =  ALGlobal.sharedInstance.bagLists
    let bag = bagList?[0]
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: CLLocationDegrees.init(bag!.latitude),
        longitude: CLLocationDegrees.init(bag!.longitude))
    let circle = MKCircle(center: center, radius: Double(radius)!)

    userMapView.add(circle)
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView,rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
    circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1
    return circleRenderer
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your renderer function is not being called because it has the wrong signature. In Swift 3, the correct signature is

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
```

Also you need to make sure that `self` is the map view's delegate.

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting a compiler warning about this.